# updating multiple data using edit form laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code below as a part of the method inside my controller
to update multiple captions of their respective image using edit form but it is only updating 1 caption with the last input value

```
 $captions = $request['caption'];
        foreach($captions as $key=>$caps){
            $image->update([
                'caption' => $captions[$key]
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: Would need to see more code (specifically where `$image` comes from) to be sure, but probably `$image` needs to be re-instantiated within the `foreach`.

Comment: @mopo922 here is the code of image came from $image = Image::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();

Comment: So the `firstOrFail()` means you're only getting the first image associated with this user. Then in your loop, you're updating the caption for that same image over & over, until you're left with the last caption.

Comment: @mopo922 yes i think so, but im stuck on it can't find a way to fix this now, sorry about my bad code logic :( can you help me out of this one?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate your `$image` inside of the `foreach` loop so you're updating a different image each time. Something like this:

```
$captions = $request['caption'];
foreach($captions as $key=>$caps){
    $image = Image::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('id', '=', $key) // pseudo code
        ->firstOrFail();
    $image->update([
        'caption' => $captions[$key]
    ]);
}
```

I don't know what your database structure looks like, or if `$key` corresponds to an image ID, but the `// pseudo code` line is simply to suggest that you need to grab the image that should be associated with this caption.

Comment: thanks, but my image and caption belongs to 1 table that's why the "->where('image_id','=',$key)" gives an error message "No query results for model"

Comment: @seamons How can you correlate each caption with the correct image?

Comment: i have this field im my Image table "id | user_id | filepath | caption"

Comment: @seamons I still don't see how you know which caption from `$request['caption']` goes with which image in the database? That's what you have to figure out, and the answer will tell you what to do for my `// psuedo code` line.

Comment: should i create another table for the caption to fix this problem? or add another field to my Image table to have solution on this? I think that is my problem the code doesnt know which data it will update

Comment: @seamons If it were me, I would set it up so that the array keys in `$request['caption']` are the image ID that goes with the caption. Then you could use my code as-is.